# On Grid with grouping feature, change the sorting order in the grouped column

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

As an example, suppose that a grid exists with the following columns: Name, Age, Pet.

Also suppose the only possible pets are from the set (Dog, Cat, Fish).

I have applied the grouping feature with `groupField: 'Pet'`. By default, the grid is rendered with the rows grouped by pets in the ascending order of possible pets.

Something like:

```
Pet: Cat (30)
----------------
[30 Cat Rows]

Pet: Dog (10)
----------------
[10 Cat Rows]

Pet: Fish (10)
----------------
[10 Cat Rows]
```

I want to control the sorting order of the grouped column too, so the order of the groups can be descending too:

```
Pet: Fish (10)
----------------
[10 Cat Rows]

Pet: Dog (10)
----------------
[10 Cat Rows]

Pet: Cat (30)
----------------
[30 Cat Rows]
```

The above should be supported for any column (on which grouping is possible) in the grid.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [groupDir](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-groupDir), setting groupDir: 'DESC' should work..